# MySQL how to build Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with four fields — `table_id`, `table_who`, `table_whom`, `table_when`.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
table_id | table_who | table_whom | table_when
-------------------------------------------------------    
1        | aaa       |   w1       | 02/10/2012 19:05:03

2        | aaa       |   w2       | 08/10/2012 08:05:03

3        | bbb       |   w3       | 08/10/2012 08:03:05

4        | bbb       |   w4       | 07/10/2012 08:05:03
```

I would like to select all rows where:

- `table_who=”aaa”` and `(Now()-table_when)>12`
- `table_who<>”aaa”`

If I use:

```
    SELECT Table.table_id, Table.table_who, Table.table_whom, Table.table_when, Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh") AS Diff
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE (((Table.table_who)<>"aaa") AND ((Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh"))<12));
```

I have only two rows, `table_id=3` and `4`. But what I want is to have `table_ID=1`, `3` and `4`.

Comment: I’ve just realised how to do it, silly me

Comment: @Devart - thank you for your input, if you check code you will see it is formatted as hours; anyway I’ve realised how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
where (Table.table_who<>"aaa") OR (Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh")<12 AND Table.table_who="aaa")
```

if i understood right. Where its not aaa or it it aaa when now - when >12 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try that:

```
   SELECT Table.table_id, Table.table_who, Table.table_whom, Table.table_when, Format(Now()-  [table_when],"hh") AS Diff
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE (((Table.table_who)<>"aaa") AND ((Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh"))<12))
    OR (((Table.table_who)="aaa") AND ((Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh"))<12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT Table.table_id, Table.table_who, Table.table_whom, Table.table_when, Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh") AS Diff
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE (Table.table_who)<>"aaa") 
    OR ((Table.table_who)="aaa") AND ((Format(Now()-[table_when],"hh"))<12) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the conditions like you defined them:

```
WHERE
 (Table.table_who = 'aaa' AND Format(Now() - [table_when], 'hh') < 12) OR
 Table.table_who <> 'aaa'
```

You only need parentheses in some cases an should certainly not overuse them, but I like to group conditions together in a case like this, when you want (A AND B) OR C. If you write it like this, there can be no mistake about the order in which the expressions are evaluated.

A different indenting may make it even more clear, depending on what you're used to.

```
WHERE
 (
    Table.table_who = 'aaa' 
    AND Format(Now() - [table_when], 'hh') < 12
 ) 
 OR Table.table_who <> 'aaa'
```

Comment: thx mate this is exactly what I needed some nice and clean code

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is what you want:

```
WHERE (Table.table_who = "aaa" AND Table.table_when > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 DAY)) OR Table.table_who <> "aaa"
```